# jQuery fadeIn doesn't work, fadeTo works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep having issues with fading in an element after appending it to a parent.

Here's some example code I threw together: (http://jsfiddle.net/XCKJf/)

```
// test with fadeTo and fadeIn
var wrap1 = $('<div>Wrap 1</div>');
wrap1.appendTo('#container');
wrap1.fadeTo(0, 0).fadeIn();

// test with fadeTo and fadeTo - WORKS
var wrap2 = $('<div>Wrap 2</div>');
wrap2.appendTo('#container');
wrap2.fadeTo(0, 0).fadeTo(500, 1);

// test with css opacity and fadeIn
var wrap3 = $('<div>Wrap 3</div>');
wrap3.appendTo('#container');
wrap3.css('opacity', 0).fadeIn();

// test with css opacity and fadeTo - WORKS
var wrap4 = $('<div>Wrap 4</div>');
wrap4.appendTo('#container');
wrap4.css('opacity', 0).fadeTo(500, 1);
```

`wrap2` and `wrap4` fade in correctly, because they use `fadeTo()`. `wrap1` and `wrap3` do not fade in. There are no errors thrown.

Obviously I can just keep using fadeTo, but as far as I know all 4 of these elements should fade in, so I really would like know why it's behaving this way.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: What I'm thinking is that .fadeTo specifies the opacity, but .fadeIn is used specifically to unhide the element. So, fading it in from opacity:0 would not apply to .fadeIn, but if you use display:none .fadeIn would work and .fadeTo wouldn't

Comment: You're correct peterchon. It seems to work that way

Comment: Yep, that's it. Felipe answered it below. I think the jQuery team really needs to rethink this functionality. `fadeIn` is named quite literally, so IMO it should fade in an element not dependent on `display: none` being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What FadeTo does is adding a style setting its opacity to 0.

What FadeIn does is removing any style with "display: none".

So you can't show something with FadeIn that has been "hidden" with FadeTo. You could use FadeOut on the other hand since its implementation is the opposite of FadeIn putting the "display: none" on the style for you.

Comment: In your wrap3 it would probably work if you used ".css('display', 'none')" instead of "opacity" before calling "fadeIn()"

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it still seems like it should work in this case. FadeIn uses opacity to fade an element in, so it shouldn't matter if the element is set to `opacity: 0` beforehand, right? The element has never been set to `display: none` so that shouldn't be an issue. Or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: Ah, so what you're saying is for fadeIn to work, it requires the element by be `display: none`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XCKJf/3/ It looks like you're correct. Thanks! Although, it makes absolutely no sense to me that fadeIn would require an element be set to `display: none`. For anyone reading, it also works to change it to `wrap1.hide().fadeIn()`.

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm saying :)

You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/XCKJf/2/
I updated your jsfiddle so it could work

Comment: It works with "hide()" function because its implementation adds the "display: none" style on your html tag.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// test with fadeTo and fadeIn

var $container = $('#container');

var wrap1 = $('<div>Wrap 1</div>');
wrap1.fadeIn(1500).appendTo($container);

// test with fadeTo and fadeTo
var wrap2 = $('<div>Wrap 2</div>');
wrap2.fadeIn(2000).appendTo($container);

// test with css opacity and fadeIn
var wrap3 = $('<div>Wrap 3</div>');
wrap3.fadeIn(2500).appendTo($container);

// test with css opacity and fadeTo
var wrap4 = $('<div>Wrap 4</div>');
wrap4.fadeIn(3000).appendTo($container);
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XCKJf/4/

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is really interesting. Why would `wrap1.fadeIn(1500).appendTo($container);` work, but `wrap1.appendTo($container).fadeIn(1500);` not work? Shouldn't calling fadeIn on an element that isn't part of the DOM fail? This fadeIn function is confusing.

Comment: @Gavin::: element should be first injected into DOM then apply fading on it.

Comment: Actually, I don't mean it should fail, since obviously the animation queue doesn't even start until after the appendTo is processed. I guess how fadeIn works is the element has to be out of the document flow, or it just won't work. I don't agree with that functionality, but I'm glad I understand it now. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean the opposite, right? Apply the fading and then insert it into the DOM.